# UIAlertView not dismissing?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uialertview

I have a few ViewController subclasses inside a UINavigation controller. I have successfully used UIAlertViews elsewhere in the application, and I know how to set the delegate and include the correct delegate methods, etc.

In a ViewController with a UITableView, I have implemented a 'pull to refresh' with a UIRefreshControl. I have a separate class to manage the downloading and parsing of some XML data, and in the event of a connection error, I post a notification. The view controller containing the table view observes this notification and runs a method where I build and display an alert:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Error" message:[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;
[alertView show];
```

The alert displays correctly, but the cancelButton is unresponsive - there is no way to dismiss the alert! Putting similar code (identical, but without the notification's userinfo) in the VC's viewDidLoad method creates an alert that behaves normally.

Is the refresh gesture hogging first responder or something? I have tried [alertView becomeFirstResponder]. I would be grateful for any advice…

Update: screenshot included… is this the right info? (can't embed this image for lack of reputation) https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CGqS.png

Comment: First responder does not influence touch events. Do you perhaps display the alert from a background thread?

Comment: Where is this code called? And where is the delegate method??

Comment: It's not being displayed from the background, though the structure might be a little strange: the UIRefreshControl tells the singleton data store class to have yet another class to make the url request. The notification is posted by this class's connection:didFailWithError: method.

Comment: This code is called in the method named by addObserver…:      

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(connectionAlert:) name:@"MTRConnectionError" object:nil];`

Comment: `- (void)connectionAlert:(NSNotification *)notification {
    
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Error" message:[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;
    [alertView show];
    
}`

Comment: Does self implement any of the delegate methods?

Comment: The delegate methods I have tried are in the same VC… but in my past experience the alert dismisses with any button click whether or not the delegate method is present. (Yes, I have attempted to use `[alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];` and `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`

Comment: Basically, are you using any of the delegate methods? If not, set the delegate to nil. I'm thinking maybe you have a delegate method that is blocking the dismissal.

Comment: nil delegate doesn't do the trick. I have a feeling that it has something to do with the tableview and the refresh… though I've tried endRefreshing the UIRefreshControl before creating the alert, still no luck!

Comment: My only guess is that you have something else that is blocking the main thread and preventing this from dismissing.

Comment: @hukir I've seen that interface objects are always supposed to run in the main thread, but I'm only backgrounding one operation in a completely separate VC. Is there a way to force the UIAlertView on the main thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**

It seems like you have a deadlock or your thread is stuck waiting. You should look at your code and see what causes this.

**Original answer which lead to update in OP**

Make sure the alert is shown on the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //Open alert here
});
```

Comment: Thank you - interesting result, the alert is now not displayed. Does this indicate that some other process is hogging the main thread?

Comment: @scsiduck Seems so, yes. In the debugger, hit pause (after the UI is stuck) and post a screenshot of what you see there.

Comment: Added image url to original post

Comment: @scsiduck You seem to have a deadlock or the code is stuck waiting for a response that never comes.

Comment: Thank you. I have a pretty bad knowledge of threading stuff… 

I had transplanted some of the urlrequest code from another class where it was using NSRunLoop to stay alive and this was hanging things up.

Comment: @scsiduck Just an advice, you should not be using `NSRunloop run` on the main thread. Instead, you should use `NSURLConnection`'s asynchronous API, or better yet, iOS7 `NSURLSession`'s asynchronous API.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a solution per se, but I might try two quick things as you troubleshoot:

1) Hardcode some text in the UIAlert, rather than passing in the notification object. See if there is any change in behavior.

2) Try adding another button to the alert and an accompanying method to catch it. So you'll see if the delegate is getting ny buttons messages at all.

Comment: Thanks for the advice… Hardcoding the 'message' doesn't have an effect, and the delegate messages don't ever seem to be called. I verified that using the same code in the viewDidLoad method displays an alert that can be dismissed, and the delegate messages are called.

Comment: Do the buttons appear to get "pressed" even though the delegate methods aren't called? As in, might there just be something invisible in front of the alert that is eating your touches?

Comment: The button doesn't seem to be pressed, good idea. I'm not creating any views programmatically apart from the alert. Everything else is just created in the storyboard.

Comment: Three things to try: 1) Comment out "alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;"  2) try "bringingSubViewToFront" on the alertView. 3) Just for troubleshooting: instead of adding an alertView, try just creating a button on the fly and seeing if that is tappable.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a tag to the `alertView`

```
alertView.tag = 0;
```

Then create the method `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` in the view controller.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
    if (alertView.tag == 0) {
        [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of the tag if there is only one alert view?

Comment: No point other than to provide a way to distinguish between multiple alert views.  Seeing as the OP only has the one alert, they could forget the tag and simply run [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES]; inside the delegate method.

See [Apple's UIAlertViewDelegate documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html) for more info the on the delegate methods that need to me implemented with custom buttons.

Comment: @timgcarlson unfortunately, still unresponsive